# Can joker be played with no other tiles?

Tags: rummikub, joker

When playing Rummikub, if you have joker tile, no other tiles to play with it and nobody has gone out can you use it any where on the board?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in [the rules](https://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/leisure/brain-games/rummikub1.htm) that prevents you from playing a joker as a single tile, as long as you had your initial meld. It can be advantageous if another player is about to win and you don't want the 30 points penalty.